# Get Image URL from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm uploading an image to firebase and then I try to retrieve the URL once the upload is completed but I'm getting this error.

```
[Error] Error uploading image:  – TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.storageRef.getDownloadURL') — speakers.js:150
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.storageRef.getDownloadURL') — speakers.js:150
    (anonymous function) (speakers.js:161)
    promiseReactionJob
```

The image gets uploaded just fine but I'm not getting the URL.

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

function uploadPhoto() {
    if (selectedFile != null) {
        var filePath = "Speaker Images/" + selectedFile.name + Date.now();
        var upload = storageRef.child(filePath).put(selectedFile).then(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadUrl) {
                console.log(downloadUrl);
                uploadImageUrl = downloadUrl;
                if (docId != null) {
                    updateSpeaker();
                } else {
                    createNewSpeaker();
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error uploading image: ", error);
        });
    } else {
        if (docId != null) {
            updateSpeaker();
        } else {
            createNewSpeaker();
        }
    }
}
```

The snapshot seems to be fine.

```
[Log] Ee {bytesTransferred: 30255, totalBytes: 30255, state: "success", metadata: Object, task: e, …} (speakers.js, line 150)
```

Comment: Log out `snapshot` and see what returns

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I've added the results of the snapshot log. It seems to be fine.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I've added the storageRef definition to my question.

Comment: `var upload` isn't going to work. That promise doesn't return anything and that isn't async/await function

Comment: @MaxBaldwin The upload works. I'm able to see the file in my storage in Firebase console.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `snapshot` variable is of type [`UploadTaskSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot), which doesn't have a `storageRef` child. You're probably looking for `snapshot.ref`:

```
snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadUrl) {
    ...
```

Comment: Well, I feel dumb. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Reference.getDownloadURL

```
const url = await storage().ref('images/profile-1.png').getDownloadURL();
```

https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage